# Import interface in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

In a Meteor app that uses Angular 2, I want to create a custom data type, something like this:

```
interface MyCustomType {
  index: number;
  value: string;
}
```

I then want to use this custom type in multiple files. I've tried creating a separate file named "mycustom.type.ts", with the following content:

```
export interface MyCustomType {
  index: number;
  value: string;
}
```

I then attempt to import this type so that it can be used in another file:

```
import MyCustomType from "./mycustom.type"
```

However, Atom reports the following error:

```
TS Error File '/.../mycustom.type.ts' is not a module ...
```

How should I be declaring and importing types, so that they can be used in multiple places?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should rather import it like that :

```
import { MyCustomType } from './mycustom.type';
```

**don't forget the `{` and `}`.**

Comment: I have the same issue but I already had the brackets {  } so this didn't work for me. Any other possible solutions?

Comment: This answer is only part of the issue. If you want to `import` a module you need to set the interface as exportable - .e.g. `export interface MyCustomType { `

Comment: If you want to import you have to export. Of course. Plus, OP already exported it so I really don't see your point here.

Answer (score 18):

I am adding this answer because the accepted one is incomplete. You have two issues:

One, you need to add `export` to your interface so that you can `import` it as a module:

`export interface MyCustomType {
  index: number;
  value: string;
}`

Second you need to add the curly brackets `{ }` to the import statement:

`import { MyCustomType } from './mycustom.type';`

Comment: What is the purpose of the curly brackets { }?

Comment: @alibenmessaoud for the `import` it describes which modules to import from the file. e.g. `import { ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleC } from './modulefile'`

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the path you are inside the component try change ./ with ../

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of top answers but still i get the same error then I understand moreover [@edzillion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65025/edzillion) issues one issue can be raise this error .

> One, you need to add export to your interface so that you can import
>   it as a module:
>
> Second you need to add the curly brackets { } to the import statement:

**Third: your interface name must be match your file name(file that interface exist in it).**

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is in the path:

Kindly refer below example:

If your file in another folder then refer below:

```
import { IPosts } from "../interfaces/iposts.type";
```

iposts.type.ts :

```
export interface IPosts {
   userId: number;
   id: number;
   title: string;
   body: string;
}
```